# Ruby: setting a new hash with an array of keys/values

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm learning Ruby via RubyMonk. In the solution to the [waiter robot problem](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/33-advanced-arrays/lessons/97-array-alternative-uses#solution4269), there's a line of code that creates a new hash using an array:

```
o = Hash[*order]
```

given

```
order = [:table, 1, :sandwich, "denver", :drink, "mango shake"]
```

I understand what's being done here and how the splat operator works. However, I'm confused about the syntax for creating this hash. [RubyDoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) says that `::[]` is really the method being called, so I was able to determine that `o = Hash::[](*order)` is the same thing. But why can this be shortened to just `Hash[*order]`? Is this a special construct that gets interpreted by the parser, or is there another reason? Along the same lines, why don't any of the following work?

```
o = Hash.new
o.[](*order)
```

or

```
o = Hash.new
o[*order]
```

or even something like `o = {}[*order]`

I know these *shouldn't* work; I'm just not sure why. I think I'm confused by the usage of `Hash[*order]` without first instantiating a hash with `Hash.new`. Is this an example of the difference between class methods and instance methods?

(As a side note, it seems to me that `o = {*order}` should work, but it doesn't.)

Can someone explain what's going on here, and if there are alternate ways to add values from an array into a hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is this an example of the difference between class methods and instance methods?*

Exactly.

*But why can this be shortened to just `Hash[*order]`?*

Ruby interprets `some_object[]` as a call to the method named `[]` on `some_object`.  This isn't special for Hashes, you can implement a `[]` method in any class of your own and use that syntax.

*Can someone explain what's going on here, and if there are alternate ways to add values from an array into a hash?*

`Hash[*order]` calls a class method (`Hash#[]`) which creates a new Hash.  `o.[](*order)` doesn't work for the same reason you can't call `new` on it: `{}.new` doesn't make any sense.  You can't call a class method on an instance of the class.

You can add values with `merge`:

```
o = Hash.new
o.merge(Hash[*order])
```

`o = {*order}` doesn't work because `{}` is the syntax for a Hash literal, and putting `*order` in there doesn't make sense.

`Hash(*order)` is [Kernel#Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash), a method that expects only one argument.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Why then can't you do `Hash(*order)`? I'm confused as to how it makes sense to use square brackets here.

Comment: @sgroves That syntax calls `Kernel#Hash`, linked to in the last line of my updated answer.

Comment: `Hash[]` is a convenience class method, likewise when you call `object[]` it's a different method than `Hash[]`. Checkout the [Hash class docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) and look for the two different `[]` methods. Also `[]` is a special parse case in the language, it basically does `object.[](args)`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks Azolo. Knowing that the `[]` means something special to the interpreter makes it clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `Hash(*order)` you're actually calling the `Hash` method in the `Kernel` module, which is not the same as calling the `[]` method in the `Hash` class. See the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash) for `Kernel#Hash` to see what's going on under the hood there.

Comment: `Hash(*order)` calls `Kernel#Hash`.  `Hash[*order]` in fact does call the public class method on Hash linked to in the question.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I've updated my answer since I meant to write `Hash(*order)` to begin with.